# Is there a way to get the current rendering frame number?

Tags: rendering, animation

Is there a way to get the frame number of the current animation rendering happening in a particular render mode.

This is to estimate the render time required to complete a job.

And, also to troubleshoot the machines, when any render errors happen.

Comment: FWIW, there is already a [render time estimation add-on](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Render_Time_Estimation). Full disclosure: I wrote that add-on. However, it still works and could give you some insight on how to write your own script.

Answer (score 5):

Whats not really clear is how you mean 'get', since Blender isn't actively responding to events for example. Nevertheless, there are ways to do this.

### Use the "Placeholder" render option

This writes an empty file, before rendering starts, other tools can check for these files to see which file is currently rendering.

With users and file ownership, its possible to check the file owner to see which system created the file.

*Of course its possible Blender is interrupted, so, you may end up needing some supervision scripts to ensure the state is clean before starting.*

### Use Python "Handlers"

Blender has events you can subscribe to using [bpy.app.handlers](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html).
This is a catch-all since Python is very flexible.

In this case I think you would want the `render_pre` handler, which you can run when immediately before rendering.

eg:

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def render_handler(scene):
    filepath_to_render = scene.render.frame_path()
    print("Render Handler:", bpy.data.filepath, filepath_to_render)

    # access a file, log information over the network... whatever :)

bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(render_handler)
```

### Inspect Blender's Output

Blender prints render information to the `stdout`,

You can log this to a file, and inspect the file for lines formatted as follows:

```
Fra:1 Mem:15.47M (0.00M, Peak 15.47M) | Time:00:00.00 | Preparing Scene data
Fra:1 Mem:15.47M (0.00M, Peak 19.87M) | Time:00:00.14 | Sce: Scene Ve:8 Fa:6 La:0
```

Even though this isn't 100% fool proof (its possible some Python script prints `Fra:123`), its easy enough to make a regular expression to parse the frame with reasonable certainty that its not mistaking output from elsewhere.

This is a simple example of a script that extracts the frame from a log-file, eg:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
Get the current rendering frame from Blender's text output, eg:

python3 frame_from_log.py /path/to/file.log
"""

import sys
LOGFILE = sys.argv[-1]

frame = None
with open(LOGFILE, 'rb') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for l in reversed(lines):
    if l.startswith(b'Fra:'):
        frame = int(l[4:].split()[0])
        break
    elif l.startswith(b'Saved:'):
        # we're not currently rendering if it saved, early exit!
        break

if frame is not None:
    print("Frame found:", frame)
else:
    print("No frame found")
```

You may want to optimize it only to read the last lines of the file (for very long logs). but its a start.

Comment: I already use placeholders to let other machines know that a particular frame is being rendered.

while many machines are working on the same job, what I want is to know which machine currently rendering which frame.

could you guide me on the usage of the above script?
should i save this as a py file and run it using -p option while running through command line?

or should this be a script inside the blend file?

P.S.
this is the first time something like this is attempted by me. and I have got absolutely no knowledge about using python in blender.

Comment: the log idea, is good, hadn't thought about it.
the file system idea is great !!!

will try both and let you know

thanks for the help.

Comment: @Siva couldn't the filesystem be configured so the file owner is set for the files that they create? - then you can just check who owns each file.  Failing that, The handler example could write an identifier such as the systems IP into a file.